# Django images don't fill height

Tags: html, css, django

I am currently working on a django blog. However, I am experiencing some difficulties with the size of the post thumbnails. Here's a picture:

[image]

What I marked in yellow is how the image should be filling the space. The width is fine, but the heigh isn't working well as you can see.

Here's the code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<style>
  img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    
  }
</style>

        <!-- Post-->
        {% for obj in object_list %}
        <div class="row d-flex align-items-stretch">
          {% if not forloop.first and not forloop.last %}
          <div class="image col-lg-5"><img src="{{ obj.thumbnail.url }}" alt="..."></div> #Here's the image
          {% endif %}
          <div class="text col-lg-7">
            <div class="text-inner d-flex align-items-center">
              <div class="content">
                <header class="post-header">
                  <div class="category">
                    {% for cat in obj.categories.all %}
                    <a href="#">{{ cat }}</a>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </div>
                  <a href="{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}">
                    <h2 class="h4">{{ obj.title }}</h2>
                    </a>
                </header>
                <p>{{ obj.overview|linebreaks|truncatechars:200 }}</p>
                <footer class="post-footer d-flex align-items-center"><a href="#" class="author d-flex align-items-center flex-wrap">
                    <div class="avatar"><img src="{{ obj.author.profile_picture.url }}" alt="..." class="img-fluid"></div>
                    <div class="title"><span>{{ obj.author }}</span></div></a>
                  <div class="date"><i class="icon-clock"></i> {{ obj.timestamp|timesince }} ago</div>
                  <div class="comments"><i class="icon-comment"></i>{{ obj.comment_count }}</div>
                </footer>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          {% if forloop.first or forloop.last %}
          <div class="image col-lg-5"><img src="{{ obj.thumbnail.url }}" alt="..."></div> #Here's the image
          {% endif %}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </section>
```

I have no idea where the error is. I've tried to debug the problem but I haven been able to debug it

Comment: had the same problem many times i switched to a different alternative: easy-thumbnails, makes it real easy to manipulate images

Comment: Could you tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

The way I see it, it's doing exactly what it's supposed to.
You put the image inside a column, then the image has 100% of the width, and because this is just an image inside a div (no display flex on the column or tricks involved), 100% height is just not gonna work and the default height of the image is used.

And even if it did work, and the images where 100% both on height and width, they'll probably end up all stretched and deformed in different resolutions, because the ratio of width:height probably changes.

I usually skip this dilemma by avoiding the use of the img tag altogether, and setting the images as background-images in the column with the 'image' class. Then set the background-size to "cover", and background-position to "center". You probably also need to set a minimum height for this column, so the images don't completely disappear when the columns stack on top of each other on smaller screens.

You can add a class like

```
<style>
  .image {
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    min-height: 200px; // this size is arbitrary, choose what suits best
  }
</style>
```

And then add the image on the iteration like so

```
    <div class="image col-lg-5" style="background-image: url('{{ obj.thumbnail.url }}');"></div>
```

Comment: Should I create a css class with de background lmage then?

Comment: Just edited my response to add the example with the css class.

Answer (score 0):

first you install it using pip install easy-thumbnails

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'easy_thumbnails',
    ]
```

then you do your migrations,and use it in your templates, this is from a project of mine:

```
{% load thumbnail %}

{% for image in images %}
  <div class="image">
    <a href="{{ image.get_absolute_url }}">
      {% thumbnail image.image 300x300 crop="smart" as im %}
      <a href="{{ image.get_absolute_url }}">
        <img src="{{ im.url }}">
      </a>
    </a>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

you can play with the details 300x300 as you wish, also the crop is optional but very useful

if you have trouble showing images add : THUMBNAIL_DEBUG = True to your settings

here is the docs https://easy-thumbnails.readthedocs.io/en/

Comment: I've done it and there's still the same problem